# How to maintain a focus on Input field when popper is shown in Material-ui

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-hook-form

I want to add Accept and Reject buttons on input fields which should appear only when user has focused on input fields. Similar to what we get in Jira.
[image]

I tried creating a similar component with material-ui. Problem is, when I focus in input field, it shows those two buttons but later I am unable to type inside input box.

Can someone please help me on this?
Below is a code sandbox: 
https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-2hrc4?file=/demo.tsx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to do what you wanted using ButtonGroup and conditional rendering (not with popover). My guess is Popover has some z-index maybe because of which we can't enter anything in input, not entirely sure about it.

Check out if it works for you - https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-sgpt6?file=/demo.tsx

You forgot to handle state of your input too -

```
     <FilledInput
        id="filled-adornment-weight"
        value={value}
        aria-describedby="filled-weight-helper-text"
        inputProps={{
          "aria-label": "weight"
        }}
        onFocus={handleClick}
        onChange={e => setValue(e.target.value)} //set value//
      />
```

Comment: oh that's awesome.. This is exactly what I was trying to achieve.. Thanks a lot for quick response.

Comment: @Mahesh Glad to be of help. :D

Answer (score 1):

I think this could help someone who haves the same issue.

```
//functions and other stuffs

     <FilledInput
        id="filled-adornment-weight"
        value={value}
        aria-describedby="filled-weight-helper-text"
        inputProps={{
          "aria-label": "weight"
        }}
        aria-owns="simple-popover"
        aria-haspopup="true"
        onFocus={handleClick}
        onChange={(e) => setValue(e.target.value)}
      />

      <Popover
        id="simple-popover"
        open={open}
        onClose={handleClose}
        anchorEl={anchorEl}
        anchorOrigin={{
          vertical: "bottom",
          horizontal: "center"
        }}
        transformOrigin={{
          vertical: "top",
          horizontal: "center"
        }}
        disableAutoFocus
        disableEnforceFocus
        disableRestoreFocus
      >
    /*Popover content */
</Popover>
```

Here is a fork of the codesandbox of @Atin Singh
https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-dyki7k?file=/demo.tsx